# ElasticSearch: Filtered aliases , Filters are not always applied?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was referring to ElasticSearch documentation i.e
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/securing-aliases.html#_filtered_aliases
It has below definition for  Filtered aliases:

> **Filtered aliases:**
>    Aliases can hold a filter, which allows to select a subset of documents that can be accessed out of all the
>   documents that the physical index contains.
>   **These filters are not always applied** and should not be used in place of document level security.

Can any one explain what does it mean when they say "These filters are not always applied".
My assumption is if we create a filtered alias , filters should always be applied, am I missing something?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that if someone accesses the underlying index directly without going through the alias, then the filter will not be applied. So, if document-level security is mandated, filtered aliases should not be used to achieve that.

Filtered aliases merely provided a "view" of the underlying indexes, but don't prevent anyone from accessing any document by going directly through the underlying indexes.